# Automatic Login for Internal Users - Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have configured Azure AD Auth (v2) in a .NET Core application using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore) and sign in and sign out are working properly. The guide uses the packages `Microsoft.Identity.Web` and `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI`. I did not add the authorization policy of `RequireAuthenticatedUser()` since we want to allow anonymous access with some sections hidden if you are not logged in.

I now have the requirement of automatically logging in those users who are on the VPN or internal network (domain), and am not sure how to go about this. I did some digging and saw some references to seamless single sign-on, but my organizations Azure only has Federation enabled with seamless single sign-on and pass-through authentication disabled.

I've added some snippets of the guide below:

```
public class Startup
{
 ...
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
  services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd");

   services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
            // Commented out because we want everyone to be able to access, with authenticated (internal) users having more information displayed
            /*var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));*/
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
 // more code here
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();

  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapRazorPages(); });
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
 // more code here
}
```

I appreciate any advice or guidance on a path forward. Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso), Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) do not support seamless SSO .

Comment: You can  replace ADFS with [AD Connect](https://www.core.co.uk/blog/blog/replace-adfs-seamless-sign-on) Seamless Sign-On

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of Azure AD Seamless Single Sign-On to Automatically Login Internal users from Azure AD, when using  the VPN or internal network.

As mentioned in the official [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso),

***Active Directory Federation Services do not support `seamless SSO`.***

As you can see when Federation is Enabled, we do not have an option to enable Seamless sign-on

***Azure AD Connect in Portal***
[image]

[image]

Either we can migrate to `Password Hash Synchronization` or `Pass-through Authentication` methods to use seamless SSO

We have an option in portal to migrate to other cloud authentication from Federation Authentication

In Portal => Azure AD => Azure AD Connect =>[`STAGED ROLLOUT OF CLOUD AUTHENTICATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-staged-rollout)
[image]